# YiiMongoDbSuite and dropdown list

Tags: mongodb, drop-down-menu, yii, mongoid, populate

Does anybody know how to populate a dropdown list from a MongoDb collection? How do i access the MongoId object. I'm using the Yii framework with the YiiMongoDbSuite extension.

Answer (score 0):

I believe YiiMongoDbSuite returns active records of the type `CActiveRecord`.

The `_id` is simply a property of the class as such doing:

`$m = $v->_id`

Will make `$m` equal the _id of that record or active record class.

The above code may return an `MongoId` object which might be the problem you are having, in this case you ca simply do:

`$m = (string)$v->_id`

To get the string representation of the `MongoId` object.

Comment: but the following will not work '$list = CHtml::listData($industryModels, '(string)_id', 'name');
echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'industry_id', $list);'

Comment: @Simba What about `$list = CHtml::listData($industryModels, '_id', 'name');` since the `listData` methods should get the `_id` by string

Comment: i get the following error...PHP warning Illegal offset type...which based on the stack-trace means an object cannot be used as an array key

Comment: @Simba yea I looked at the source code: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail and `chtml::value` makes no give for object formed model properties. I think you are gonna have to this manually and build up an array of _ids and then push that into the listData field. Another alternative is to make a `get_id` function to return it as a string but I am unsure what this will do to the general saving of the model.